# How to make a network interface drop a defined percentage of packets

Tags: networking, iptables, testing

I want to test an application against network outage or defective network. Is there any tool to make an interface defect-prone, or otherwise simulate a poor quality connection? For example, force interface to drop 10 percent of packets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `random` module in iptables can be used to create packet loss.
For a 10% incoming packet loss:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

Resulting in this ping result from another computer:

```
--- rpi01-wifi.smythies.com ping statistics ---
247 packets transmitted, 217 received, 12% packet loss, time 246752ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.958/4.933/169.588/17.884 ms
```

Similarly for outgoing packets:

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

Resulting in this ping result from another computer:

```
--- rpi01-wifi.smythies.com ping statistics ---
1006 packets transmitted, 871 received, 13% packet loss, time 305146ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.892/7.363/476.902/35.397 ms, pipe 2
```

Combining both `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` forced packet loss, but at 0.5% probability each:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.005 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.005 -j DROP
```

Results in:

```
--- rpi01-wifi.smythies.com ping statistics ---
1000 packets transmitted, 967 received, 3% packet loss, time 253840ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.876/7.583/536.867/36.065 ms, pipe 3
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux/1088475#1088475).

Answer (score 1):

[netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) leverages functionality already built into Linux and userspace utilities to simulate networks and can do exactly what you're asking.

From their [homepage](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem).

> **Packet loss**
>
> Random packet loss is specified in the 'tc' command in percent. The
>   smallest possible non-zero value is:
>
> 232 = 0.0000000232%
>
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.1%
>
> This causes 1/10th of a percent (i.e 1 out of 1000) packets to be
>   randomly dropped.
>
> An optional correlation may also be added. This causes the random
>   number generator to be less random and can be used to emulate packet
>   burst losses.
>
> # tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.3% 25%
>
> This will cause 0.3% of packets to be lost, and each successive
>   probability depends by a quarter on the last one.
>
> Probn = .25 * Probn-1 + .75 * Random